# React native app image rendering not working

Tags: android, image, react-native, view

I am developing an app to show the images, i am using a package called

> react-native-image-zoom-viewer

but my code not showing the images. it's always a blank screen. here is my code

```
            import { Modal } from 'react-native';
            import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer';

            const images = [
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fcandypur.png?alt=media&token=601a2198-9aef-4d4f-9c70-49ec069d527f',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fcherry.png?alt=media&token=a5d1b6e9-5ad5-4a4b-a9b8-c963ffc4255a',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2FGroup-611.png?alt=media&token=a12d81b4-b0d3-4907-94d7-3ea36cbc0faf',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2FGroup-612.png?alt=media&token=71dcba62-6225-4687-930a-e608ae42db4c',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2FGroup-615.png?alt=media&token=23e9c5dc-16f3-426e-b1ce-68c35fd145b2',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fgroupgre.png?alt=media&token=5a280580-8c4b-4aef-83c4-4626174b04fa',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Folivegreen.png?alt=media&token=dc72ce64-e794-4aab-a0a9-54f134d0d5dd',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Forange.png?alt=media&token=4631ff27-26d6-4d19-9370-40893d15af8f',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fteal.png?alt=media&token=7522aea2-02c4-4f13-9cb4-e7d43ce684e9',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fyellow.png?alt=media&token=6375fd68-fd93-40b8-a989-aef0e96e10ff'
            ]

            export default class App extends React.Component {
                render: function() {
                    return (
                        <Modal visible={true} transparent={true}>
                            <ImageViewer imageUrls={images}/>
                        </Modal>
                    )
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your images array to align with the [guidelines](https://github.com/ascoders/react-native-image-viewer#basic-usage)

```
const images = [
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fcandypur.png?alt=media&token=601a2198-9aef-4d4f-9c70-49ec069d527f'},
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fcherry.png?alt=media&token=a5d1b6e9-5ad5-4a4b-a9b8-c963ffc4255a'},
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2FGroup-611.png?alt=media&token=a12d81b4-b0d3-4907-94d7-3ea36cbc0faf'},
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2FGroup-612.png?alt=media&token=71dcba62-6225-4687-930a-e608ae42db4c'},
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2FGroup-615.png?alt=media&token=23e9c5dc-16f3-426e-b1ce-68c35fd145b2'},
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fgroupgre.png?alt=media&token=5a280580-8c4b-4aef-83c4-4626174b04fa'},
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Folivegreen.png?alt=media&token=dc72ce64-e794-4aab-a0a9-54f134d0d5dd'},
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Forange.png?alt=media&token=4631ff27-26d6-4d19-9370-40893d15af8f'},
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fteal.png?alt=media&token=7522aea2-02c4-4f13-9cb4-e7d43ce684e9'},
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fyellow.png?alt=media&token=6375fd68-fd93-40b8-a989-aef0e96e10ff}'
            ]
```

To dynamically pass required array use a s follows, use array.map function to create your array.

```
import { Modal } from 'react-native';
import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer';

            const images = [
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fcandypur.png?alt=media&token=601a2198-9aef-4d4f-9c70-49ec069d527f',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fcherry.png?alt=media&token=a5d1b6e9-5ad5-4a4b-a9b8-c963ffc4255a',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2FGroup-611.png?alt=media&token=a12d81b4-b0d3-4907-94d7-3ea36cbc0faf',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2FGroup-612.png?alt=media&token=71dcba62-6225-4687-930a-e608ae42db4c',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2FGroup-615.png?alt=media&token=23e9c5dc-16f3-426e-b1ce-68c35fd145b2',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fgroupgre.png?alt=media&token=5a280580-8c4b-4aef-83c4-4626174b04fa',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Folivegreen.png?alt=media&token=dc72ce64-e794-4aab-a0a9-54f134d0d5dd',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Forange.png?alt=media&token=4631ff27-26d6-4d19-9370-40893d15af8f',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fteal.png?alt=media&token=7522aea2-02c4-4f13-9cb4-e7d43ce684e9',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fyellow.png?alt=media&token=6375fd68-fd93-40b8-a989-aef0e96e10ff'
            ]

            export default class App extends React.Component {
                render: function() {
                    return (
                        <Modal visible={true} transparent={true}>
                            <ImageViewer imageUrls={images.map(e => { return { url: e })}/>
                        </Modal>
                    )
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay can u tell me how can i make the array dynamically like this when I am calling image URLs from firebase database. actually the array is from firebase database

Comment: @tanks again but some syntax error is there sorry but I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax

<ImageViewer imageUrls={images.map(e =>{  return { url: e }})} />

Answer (score 0):

```
const images = [
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fcandypur.png?alt=media&token=601a2198-9aef-4d4f-9c70-49ec069d527f'},
              {url:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fcherry.png?alt=media&token=a5d1b6e9-5ad5-4a4b-a9b8-c963ffc4255a'}]
```

use this line for images array:

```
<ImageViewer imageUrls={images.map(e => { return { url: e.url})}/>

const bommalu = [
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fcandypur.png?alt=media&token=601a2198-9aef-4d4f-9c70-49ec069d527f',
              'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/taam-623b6.appspot.com/o/Circles%2Fcherry.png?alt=media&token=a5d1b6e9-5ad5-4a4b-a9b8-c963ffc4255a']
```

use this line for bommalu array:

```
<ImageViewer imageUrls={bommalu.map(e => { return { url: e})}/>
```